# Inverse of Trinomial with basic algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, inverse

I've been given a trinomial in the form $$ax^2 + bx -c$$ and asked to find the inverse.

I'm wondering if this can be done with basic algebra such in the case:

$$5x^2 + 3x - 5$$
$$x = 5y^2 + 3y - 5 $$
$$x -5 = 5y^2 + 3y $$
$$\frac{x-5}{3} = 5y^2 + y $$
$$\frac{x-5}{\frac{3}{5}} = y^2 + y $$

$$\sqrt{\frac{x-5}{8}} = 2y $$
$$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x-5}{8}}}{2} = y^-1$$

Or does it need to be done with a specific procedure?

Comment: how can you know that there is an inverse?

Comment: "Completing the square" is a technique used frequently with a problem of this nature.  For the example given, consider $5y^2+3y+\frac 9{20}-\frac {109}{20}$...

Comment: Also note that your algebra is a bit off... If you divide both sides by $3$, your $y^2$ coefficient becomes $\frac53$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you propose to do can be achieved by rewriting the original equation as (for example)

$$
5y^2+3y-(5+x) = 0
$$

and then solving the quadratic equation, most easily by using the quadratic formula to obtain

$$
y = \frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{20x+109}}{10}
$$

Your derivation has numerous algebraic errors in it.  If you subtract something from one side, you don't add it to the other; you subtract it from the other side also.  If you divide one side by something, you must divide the entire other side by the same thing.  And so on.